# SMART Extended Self Test on a new Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space, smart, diagnostic

Is it normal that the SMART extended self test to run for hours on a new hard disk. So far, the test is running on my laptop for 2 hours. What is it doing? If I stop the test, will it damage the hard disk? How long will it usually run?

For your references -
Hard disk - Hitachi 7200 RPM, 1 TB.
Software - Dell SupportAssist
Test - SMART Extended Self Test
Drive Status - Nothing installed, except Windows 7, drivers and Dell SupportAssist.

Comment: The fact it is taking so long indicates a hardware problem, will it damage the HDD?  Well the HDD is already failing, but no, it won't

Comment: Ramhound, it is a new hard disk mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1TB SMART might run 2-4 hours

If dell provides the `smartctl.exe` command, you can check the progress via `smartctl.exe -Hc c:\` it shows progress of the test (sometimes it hangs) and also the firmware reported test time. Look for *Self-test execution status* and *Extended/Short self-test routine recommended polling time*

install the windows version if unable to locate smartctl.exe -- http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/

full smart info: `smartctl -x c:\`

Comment: I can see the progress. http://imgur.com/aeyPzA4
But the problem is, it is been the same. Shall I copy files while the test is running? Is it safe?

Comment: yes, smart tests run in the background with low priority, so user actions are served first.